How to debug corrupt Excel File?
I have an excel file and whenever i open it with the official microsoft excel i get an error/warning message like this:
We found a problem with some content in ’File.xlsx’. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

The problem is i can read the file with most python3 libraries and google sheets just fine only microsoft excel seems to have problems with this file. I also have another version of the file that works. I think the corrupt one got corrupted during data transfer and i want to know WHY and HOW it got corrupted.
Can anybody recommend some strategies to debug this?
I tried excel logs, but they are not useful. I tried comparing the working version and the corrupt version but since it's binary it's not really helpful. If i open the two files they are exactly the same also if i export them as csv

It got corrupted because these things sometimes happen. If you can open it using another tool (google sheets, libre office, etc...), do so then save back to XLSX under another name and see if the corruption remains. If not, problem solved.

Unfortunately not. We have a process that uploads it to aws s3 and somehow this upload corrupts the file. I‘m trying to understand why so i can open a bug report and they can fix the s3 upload

So you are saying the upload process is changing the file and thus causing the corruption? Or is the excel file creation a part of the upload process? Regardless, using a file comparison tool (excel or after converting to zip) may shed more light on where the corruption is.

You may also want to see if, once uploaded, the file gets processed somehow, causing the corruption

When you say this is binary, as an xlsx file it should be much more human readable. Take a copy of the file and rename it to have .zip extension, then unzip to a set of folders / xml files. There is a bit of an art to spelunking your way through these, but often you can find things that are blatantly wrong, or experiment with removing or changing various bits and rezipping.
